# Using external widget in an android app

Tags: android, android-layout

[AndroidTagGroup](https://github.com/2dxgujun/AndroidTagGroup) is a widget for adding Tags. I am trying to use it in my app. I have added dependency `compile 'me.gujun.android.taggroup:library:1.4@aar'` , and am using it as

```
<me.gujun.android.taggroup.TagGroup
    android:id="@+id/tag_group"
    style="@style/TagGroup" />
```

But the layout is not getting rendered and is giving two errors, 
`Failed to find style 'tagGroupStyle' in current theme`  and `Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?` . I cant find any other theme related to TagGroup, the theme i am using is appTheme. I tried defining `TagGroup` style in the styles.xml, but no use.

**Edit**

The render error is shown in Android studio studio. Even if i build and run the app, I cant see the widget in the app.

**Edit 2**

As @CommonsWare suggested, after adding Tags i can see the widget in app. Only issue remaining is the rendering issue, which from the comments seems like a android studio issue.

Comment: "But the layout is not getting rendered" -- are you referring to the Android Studio layout editor preview? If so, that has long had problems with third-party libraries.

Comment: Yes, Android Studio layout editor preview - it shows render errors. So can i safely skip it ?

Comment: "Even if i build and run the app, I cant see the widget in the app" -- that may be a separate issue. Did you give it any tags to show (e.g., via `setTags()`)? "So can i safely skip it ?" -- well, to a large extent, you have no choice.

Comment: @CommonsWare. ahh i didn't add any tags, probably that's why i cant see it. Will verify that.